# Is HTML5 Socket.IO available in C++?

Tags: javascript, c++, html, websocket

I have a server that creates a **websocket**.  I'm using **HTML5**, **Javascript** and **JQuery** on the client side.

My fellow-student who works on the project uses RFID technology to scan a tag.  Then he needs to send me those data from his app via the socket.

Is that possible with his preferred language **C++**?  And how does he need to do that?

Comment: Open a socket and send the data.

Comment: Sure it's possible. Just have him communicate to the server via Websocket as well (he might prefer using some Websockets library for C++).

Comment: From what I know, there's no library for C++ that let you link your server with the client (on which socket.io runs). So, you've to write a library with C++ for socket.io. Otherwise, choose another WebSocket library.
There's ExtJS-WebSocket (https://github.com/wilk/ExtJS-WebSocket) but it's for ExtJS.

Comment: @Tony.  It does not work.  :-(

Answer (score 2):

There are some websocket implementations for C++ available. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations Unfortunately I don't have experience with any of them.

When none of these libraries works out for you, I would not recommend that you create your own implementation of WebSocket. [It's not a very simple protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) (I know what I am talking about - I wrote a websocket server in Java) and it only makes sense when the client is a web browser. When the client is able to use pure TCP/IP sockets, like a client written in C++, there is no reason to add WebSocket as another layer of indirection.

So you should rather implement an alternative network handler on your server which listens to a normal non-web socket. That would be a lot easier and also reduce protocol overhead and CPU load on client and server.

Comment: ->  Thanks for your quick response.  What alternative connection would you suggest between the two then?  Other than a websocket. My main purpose for this project is real-time data.